# assign the output of an if statement to a variable powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to assign the output of an if statement to a variable, I am New To Powershell and don't have a firm grasp of it, Any Help would be Great. Thanks!

```
$Var = if ($Title -eq "Service Route Rep"){
$Department = "Operations"}elseif ($Title -eq "AP Clerk"){
$Department = "Finance"}elseif($Title -eq "Product Development Manager")
$Department = "Operations"}      

$Title = "Service Route Rep"
$Department = "$var"

$user.department = "$Department"
```

and i receive the error

```
Set-ADUser : replace
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ADUser -instance $user
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-ADUser], 
ADInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, you are trying to set `$Var` to a value based on a conditional expression. To do so, you must evaluate the expression, and return the desired output:

```
$Var = if ($Title -eq 'Service Route Rep'){ 'Operations' }
        elseif ($Title -eq 'AP Clerk'){ 'Finance' }
        elseif ($Title -eq 'Product Development Manager') { 'Operations' }
```

In your code, you are evaluating the expression, but set `$Department` with the desired department value. This means that the expression itself is returning `$null`. Then, you take the value of `$Department`, and overwrite it in the line `$Department = "$var"`, which is setting `$Department` to `$null`.

I would recommend looking at using a [HashTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable) in this case. It is a very common pattern, as it is far more readable.

```
$TitleMap = @{}
$TitleMap.Add('Service Route Rep', 'Operations')
$TitleMap.Add('AP Clerk', 'Finance')
$TitleMap.Add('Product Development Manager', 'Operations')

$Title = "Service Route Rep"
$Department = $TitleMap[$Title]
```

You will also may note that I have used single vs. double quotes, which you can read more about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules).

Comment: For added readability I suggest to combine the hashtable creation and the assignment of its members: `$TitleMap = @{ 'Service Route Rep' = 'Operations'; 'AP Clerk' = 'Finance'; 'Product Development Manager' = 'Operations' }`. You can replace the `;` by line feed, I just can't write it as such in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

For another approach, especially if you have more items to decode.

```
$Var = Switch ($Title){ 
           'Service Route Rep'           { 'Operations' }
           'AP Clerk'                    { 'Finance'    }
           'Product Development Manager' { 'Operations' } 
           Default                 {'Title Not in list!'}
         }
```

HTH